# How to set a buttons innerHTML as an image? (Using DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am not very experienced with JS and using DOM. I have a button I am making out of JS and I want to have that button as an image.(probably should have done it the other way around but I have already built around this button).

I have tried:

```
btn.innerHTML = btn.style.backgroundImage = "Images/Notepad.png";



btn.innerHTML = "Images/Notepad.png";
```

and

```
btn.style.backgroundImage = "Images/Notepad.png";
```

Comment: You're missing the `url()` around the image url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "url(...)"

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.heise.de/download/media/notepad-26659/notepad-plusplus-jpg8_1-1-24.jpg')";
```

```css
button {
  height: 320px;
  width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
Notepad
</button>
```